# Qt mdi application with custiom UI from QtDesigner

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer

Assume I have two UI files from Qt Designer:mainform.ui stores mdiArea and figureslist.ui stores listView.

Now I'd like to create a mdi application, that can open numbers of figureList windows.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

class HelloWorldApplication(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QApplication.__init__(self, args)
        self.maindialog = MainUI(None)

class MainUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainform.ui")
        self.ui.show()

        # create child and show it
        child = self.createFiguresListView()

        # problem here (*)
        child.show()

    def createFiguresListView(self):
        child = FiguresListView()
        self.ui.mdi.addSubWindow(child)
        return child

class FiguresListView(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FiguresListView, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("figureslist.ui")


app = HelloWorldApplication(sys.argv)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But unfortunately my child window shows up collapsed without layout described in figureslist.ui, but acts like mdi child, but if I replace code marked with (*) to child.ui.show() it shows actual layout, but doesn't act like mdi child.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the parent for the ui (also, if you didn't specified minimum size in Designer, you need to do it here):

```
class FiguresListView(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FiguresListView, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("figureslist.ui", self)
        #self.setMinimumSize(400, 200)
```